# Turning WKB type integer into text for memory layer creation with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, well-known-binary

I'm creating a memory layer in PyQGIS and I need to match the geometry of the memory layer that I am building to the geometry of another layer.

After some investigation it seems to me that, as per [QGIS 2.2 Documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider) and the [QGIS 2.2 API Documentation](http://qgis.org/api/2.2/classQGis.html#a8da456870e1caec209d8ba7502cceff7), the URI defining the geometry type approximately matches the `QGis::WkbType` member enumeration text.

I know I can easily query the `WKBType` of my input layer with

```py
myWkbType = mylayer.dataProvider().geometryType()
```

However, this returns an integer, whereas the constructor requires text. Is there a simple built-in PyQGIS way to turn these constants into text, or do I need to build a hacky little reverse mapping function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGis.WkbType is a sip wrapped enum class which doesn't have a reverse mapping function like it would if it were a native python enum.

So the answer i guess would be either to wrap the class in another class with the desired python enum attributes or to write a hacky little lookup function.

Rather than all the drama of writing a wrapping class - here's a stand alone dictionary and reverse map:

```
my_WkbType = { 'WKBUnknown': 0, 'WKBPoint':1, 'WKBLineString':2, 'WKBPolygon':3, 'WKBMultiPoint':4, 'WKBMultiLineString':5, 'WKBMultiPolygon':6, 'WKBNoGeometry':7, 'WKBPoint25D':8, 'WKBLineString25D':9, 'WKBPolygon25D':10, 'WKBMultiPoint25D':11, 'WKBMultiLineString25D':12, 'WKBMultiPolygon25D':13 }

my_rev_WkbType = {v:k for k, v in my_WkbType.items()}
```

To test it you can try:

```
my_rev_WkbType[QGis.WKBPolygon]
```

Or in the context of the question:

```
my_rev_WkbType[mylayer.dataProvider().geometryType()]
```

Comment: qgis 3 has the following function: QgsWkbTypes.geometryDisplayString(int)

Answer (score 2):

Since QGIS 3.0 you can use the `displayString` and `geometryDisplayString` functions:

```
>>> QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.wkbType())
'MultiSurface'

>>> QgsWkbTypes.geometryDisplayString(layer.geometryType())
'Polygon'
```

Answer (score 0):

this post is quite old, just stumbled upon it. To get a text representation to all available WkbTypes, i ended up using this:

```
dict([(v, k) for k, v in QgsWkbTypes.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, int)])
```

Comment: Nice: much less hacky. Any chance of adding the line which would return the text for a memory layer based on the input layer as in my answer. If so I'll change to your answer as accepted.