# Converting QgsPoint() to QgsGeometry() and vice versa with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, geometry, convert

I want to convert a `QgsPoint()` to a `QgsGeometry()`, respectively a `QgsGeometry()` to a `QgsPoint()`.

Note that I am talking about `QgsPoint()`, **not** `QgsPointXY()`**!**

`QgsGeometry()` does offer a `.asPoint()` method, but this method does **not** return a `QgsPoint()`, but a `QgsPointXY()`, which is quite confusing by the way. The `.fromPoint()` method was added in v3.34, for older versions there only is a `.fromPointXY()` method.

How can I do the conversion in QGIS 3.28?

Link to the docs:

- https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html
- https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsPoint.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TLTR;***

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPoint, QgsGeometry

# QgsPoint  QgsGeometry
point_as_geom = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(10, 20, 5, 1))
# QgsGeometry  QgsPoint
geom_as_point = point_as_geom.constGet()
```

---

After reading this topic: [Difference between QgsPoint, QgsPointXY and QgsGeometry.fromPointXY() in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377881/difference-between-qgspoint-qgspointxy-and-qgsgeometry-frompointxy-in-pyqgis), one could think of the following approach:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPoint, QgsPointXY, QgsGeometry

point = QgsPoint(10, 20, 5, 1) # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
point_as_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(point)) # <QgsGeometry: Point (10 20)>
```

But, it leads *to missing some vital Z and M coordinates!*

However, there is another solution, that was provided in this thread: [Z value is lost when converting QgsGeometry to PointZ with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461648/z-value-is-lost). Simply pass your `PointZM` to the `QgsGeometry()` constructor.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPoint, QgsGeometry

point = QgsPoint(10, 20, 5, 1) # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
point_as_geom = QgsGeometry(point) # <QgsGeometry: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
```

And if one want to return, apply either [`get()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a6418c395776ccc5a13466a5d28039225) or [`constGet()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a6d80b6a9b799d6be0a3dd1d4f932db1b) method that results in point (achieved with the power of [`QgsAbstractGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometry.html) class):

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPoint, QgsGeometry

point = QgsPoint(10, 20, 5, 1) # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
point_as_geom = QgsGeometry(point) # <QgsGeometry: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
geom_as_point = point_as_geom.constGet() # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
```

In all cases, the WKB-type will be the [`PointZM`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#adf94495b88fbb3c5df092267ccc94509adff4b2ceca52a29e38b7e8637a19d26a):

```py
from qgis.core import QgsPoint, QgsGeometry, QgsWkbTypes

point = QgsPoint(10, 20, 5, 1)
print(QgsWkbTypes.displayString(point.wkbType()))
point_as_geom = QgsGeometry(point)
print(QgsWkbTypes.displayString(point_as_geom.wkbType()))
geom_as_point = point_as_geom.constGet()
print(QgsWkbTypes.displayString(geom_as_point.wkbType()))
```

---

**References:**

- [Turning WKB type integer into text for memory layer creation with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102034/turning-wkb-type-integer-into-text-for-memory-layer-creation-with-pyqgis)

Comment: It might be worth putting the two key expressions: QgsPoint to QgsGeometry: `geom = QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(10,20,5,1))` and QgsGeometry to QgsPoint: `geom.constGet()` at the top of the answer. The discussion is useful, but I almost wrote my own answer because I didn't see the key steps

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is something missing and confusing, but luckily you can do both using other methods and workarounds.

To convert a `QgsPoint()` to a `QgsGeometry()` you can use WKT as an intermediate step. First convert the point to wkt by using `.asWkt()`, then to a geometry by using `.fromWkt()`:

```py
qgs_point = QgsPoint(10,20,5,1) # create or get example point
print(qgs_point) # <QgsPoint: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
qgs_point_as_qgs_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(qgs_point.asWkt())
print(qgs_point_as_qgs_geometry) # <QgsGeometry: PointZM (10 20 5 1)>
```

To convert a `QgsGeometry()` to a `QgsPoint()` you can use the [vertices iterator](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVertexIterator.html) `.vertices().next()`, as this returns an `QgsPoint()`:

```py
qgs_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('PointZM (50 30 2 8)') # create or get example geometry
print(qgs_geometry) # <QgsGeometry: PointZM (50 30 2 8)>
qgs_geometry_as_qgs_point = qgs_geometry.vertices().next()
print(qgs_geometry_as_qgs_point) # <QgsPoint: PointZM (50 30 2 8)>
```

Comment: concerning your final note: `fromWkb` can also be used without issues, you only have to be aware that `fromWkb` is not a static member function like `fromWkt`. Therefore use `geom = QgsGeometry(); geom.fromWkb(qgs_point.asWkb())` instead.